# vmware to outside world

Tags: networking, vmware-workstation

I have a vmware workstation VM [1] running on my desktop (physical host), on the host [2] I have an interface (eth0) which connects to a switch [3] (fa0/1).

I would like to be able to speak from 1 to 3 and by speak, I mean, access the IOS CLI via ssh. How can I do this in the vmware config? Currently eth0 is in bridged mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've configured what you say correctly, then this should just work. If you don't have a DHCP server then you'll need to give your Virtual Machine an IP on the same subnet as the Host & Switch.